# how reduce RDD work in Apache Spark

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

Am currently working with Apache Spark. 
But i can not understand how reduce work after map ..

my example is pretty simple

`val map = readme.map(line => line.split(" ").size)`

i know this will return array of number of words per line but where is the key/value here to pass a reduce function ..

```
map.reduce((a,b) => {if(a>b) a else b})
```

reduce phase how it works .. (a,b) is the tuple_2 ? or its key/value from map function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have

```
val map = readme.map(line => line.split(" ").size)
```

Each element of the RDD consists of a single number, the number of words in a line of the file.

You could count all the words in your dataset with `map.sum()` or `map.reduce( (a,b) => a+b )`, which are equivalent.

The code you have posted:

```
map.reduce((a,b) => {if(a>b) a else b})
```

would find the maximum number of words per line for your entire dataset.

The `RDD.reduce` method works by converting every two elements it encounters, which at first are taken from pairs of RDD rows, to another element, in this case a number.  The aggregation function should be written so it can be nested and called on the rows in any order.  For example, subtraction will not yield useful results as a `reduce` function because you can not predict ahead of time in what order results would be subtracted from one another.   Addition, however, or maximization, still works correctly no matter the order.